# Most Efficient MySQL (An Interview Query)

Tags: mysql, select

Recently in an interview, I had the following problem:

I have a database with the following tables (for the sake of this example, let's say that these tables make sense):

- User(id, name, cc_id)
- CreditCard(id)
- Movie(id, name)
- Purchase(movie_id, cc_id)

I want to find the names of customers who bought the movie "Dark Knight".

My answer when along the lines of:

```
SELECT name FROM User AS u
    INNER JOIN CreditCard AS cc ON u.id = cc.id
    INNER JOIN Purchase AS p ON p.movie_id = 
        (SELECT id FROM Movie AS m WHERE m.name = "Dark Knight") AND cc.id = p.cc_id
```

Syntax aside, I was wondering if this is a more efficient solution to this problem.

Comment: wth... why did they have the user have a cc_id and not a cc have a u_id? weird.

Comment: You know what... maybe I had forgotten to put it, but I guess just for a learning experience, let's just say that that's how it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be better to just join the `movie` table too and don't join the `creditcard`

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM `User` AS u
INNER JOIN Purchase AS p ON p.cc_id = u.cc_id
INNER JOIN movie m on p.movie_id = m.id
WHERE m.name = 'Dark Knight'
```

Comment: So in this case a JOIN would be more efficient than a SELECT?

Comment: Yes. inner selects are slow.

Comment: Normally a join is better than a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name from User as u
    JOIN CreditCards as cc on cc.id = u.cc_id
    JOIN Purchase AS p ON p.cc_id = c.id
    JOIN Movie AS m on m.id = p.movie_id
WHERE m.name = 'Dark Night';
```